# Selecting radio property through jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors

how to select value of  through jquery. is it possible to select the radio button through its name property..please any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  $(":radio[name='INSERTNAMEHERE']").bind("click", function(){
          alert('you clicked on radio button name : INSERTNAMEHERE');
    });
```